# Debugging VB6 Code From Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, vb6

I have .NET 3.5 web application which uses some COM dll created in VB6.
I have source code for both. Also I have pdb file for the COM dll.
I would like to load the VB6 dll code inside Visual Studio 2010 for debugging.

I am able to step into dll code from VS If I loaded the COM app in VB6 IDE.
Since I am new to VB, debugging using VB6 IDE is bit tedious for me.
So I wanted to debug the COM app code inside Visual Studio 2010.

I followed the instructions in [Robgruen's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robgruen/archive/2004/11/09/254602.aspx)

The problem is VS2010 automatically creating Interop dll for the corresponding COM dll,
and It uses the Interop dll only. While debugging when I try to manually load the Symbol file for the COM dll(let's say MyComApp.dll) It fails and VS is instructing me to load Interop.MyComApp.pdb file. But I have MyComApp.pdb only.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not debug VB6 code in Visual Studio 2010 at any level higher than the compiled assembly code.

You can however convert your VB6 dll project to VB 2010 then use it in Visual Studio 2010.
Just drag and drop your VB6 project to Visual Studio 2010 (drag project to icon of VS 2010 then drop) and upgrade wizard will automatically convert it.
Or just use Artinsoft programs.
Good Luck! :)

Comment: Are you sure you can't debug VB6 in VS2010? Other people seem to manage using [this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367332/stepping-through-vb6-com-object-wrapped-by-net-class)