# debugging vb6 dll through wcf client

Tags: wcf, debugging, vb6, remote-debugging

I have a VB6 dll which has been used by a wcf service in Machine A. In vb6 dll i have  a function called createaccount () . In machine A , this service has been hosted . In machine B i have a client which consumes this service and call the method present inside this service (indirectly call the method createaccount () present inside vb6 DLL). Now what i want is when this call come to machine B break point should hit which  i have set inside vb6 dll(inside createaccount ()) . Is there any way to do all this ?

Without debugging it svery difficult to trace the error .
Plese help me on this..
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Visual Basic 6 is not the same thing as VB.NET.  I doubt you'll be able to debug VB6 inside Visual Studio - at least not without having to do some work to do so.

Comment: can you please help me on it ?
is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Take a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11882898/745969

Answer (score 0):

On machine A, open your project (for the DLL) and run it in the IDE with your breakpoint set.  When connecting from a client, the running code will be used and your breakpoint will hit.

The only trick that I can think of, is that when you run your project on machine A, make sure that there are no other programs accessing the compiled DLL.  For instance, if your WCF is hosted in IIS, recycle IIS first so that any references to the compiled DLL are released.  On the next connect, it will use the one running in the IDE.