# Debugging VB6 project that calls a .Net(C#) dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, vb6

I have been stump in this problem for a few hours now. I hope someone has had a similar problem to this.

We have developed a prototype .Net(C#) dll using VS2010, and would like to be able to call this dll in a both C# applications and VB6 application.

My question is:

**Is it possible to debug a VB6 application that is calling a .Net dll? I get an error message "*Automation Error The system cannot find the file specified*"**

The error message suggests that there is something missing for my VB6 app to find the .Net dll.

I am aware that if the VB6 application has been compiled, and the .exe has been created,  the VB6 will successfully call the .Net dll functionality when using the .exe

However it is important that we can debug through our VB6 application. Unfortunately debugging does not allow you to step over the line of code instantiating the .Net DLL's class object. I can't seem to do this.

NOTE: I have looked around forums and MSDN documentation and I mostly find solution for calling a VB6 dll in .NET; which is unfortunately the opposite of what we need to do.

NOTE: I have already registered the compiled .Net(C#) assembly, and referenced it in the VB6 project.

I have however found these two pages, which seemed to be what we need, but its a solution for calling a .NET(c#) dll generated using VS2005. This doesnt seem to work when the .NET(C#) dll was generated using VS2010.

[site1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2007/07/03/debugging-hybrid-vb6-net-applications.aspx)
[site2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730840%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#dbughybvb6_topic3)

If someone could give any suggestions or direct me somewhere I can get one, that would be great.

Thanks

**SOLUTION**
Thanks to @HansPassant, I have found the solution.
To debug a VB6 project that contains a C# .NET assembly, you need to register the .NET dll through both "*regasm*" and "*gacutil*", then make sure to close and reopen the VB6 application before you start debugging.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to do the debugging from the VB 6 side (i.e., from the VB 6 IDE)? That's not going to be possible—the VB 6 debugger works *only* with VB 6 code. It can't handle native code at all, and it certainly can't handle MSIL (.NET) code since that hadn't even been invented yet when VB 6 came out.

Comment: I guess it depends on the .Net framework you use to compile it. The examples you've found are the opposite since the visual studio versions try to keep the backwards compatibility

Comment: wow good point @CodyGray. I didn't figure it that out, you're right

Comment: Redeclare your .NET object as "As Object" (temporarily), should work much better.

Comment: @Arvo: Why? What do you think it's declared as now? Why would changing it to `As Object` make it "work much better"? How is that going to allow you to step into native/MSIL code from VB 6?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question (I thought that OP couldn't instantiate .NET object properly under VB6 - "not allow you to step over the line of code"). If problem is in debugging .NET code, then best is to use in VB6 built executable. Maybe it would be possible debug in both environments simultaneosly (using vb6.exe as host process for .NET dll); I haven't tried that actually.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, it does seem that the only way I could actually test that the .Net dll works is by building the VB6 project and running the executable, which is fine and possible. Unfortunately the target VB6 project that will need to use this .Net DLL is a such a  big project that rebuilding it actually takes some time. 

In effect we would need to complete the .Net dll before we could confirm that everything it should do will actually work when it is called by the VB6 app. 

Another option I have thought of was to write a mini VB6 application to cover the use of the .NET dll

Comment: Just as a suggestion, you might consider trying to cover this requirement using unit tests and mocking your .NET dependency.  I wrote my own, so I can't offer much help finding a good VB6 unit testing framework, but it shouldn't be too hard to find something.

Comment: I suggest accepting Hans' answer rather than commenting about it in the question. That is more noticeable to others.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367332/stepping-through-vb6-com-object-wrapped-by-net-class

Comment: FWIW the VS 2015 debugger will debug a VB6 application.

Answer (score 12):

This is not a problem, VB6 uses its own debugger that doesn't get in the way of any other debugger, including the managed one for C# code.

You start from your C# class library project, ensure it is selected as the start project.  Project + Properties, Debug tab.  Select the "Start external program" option and enter the path to the VB6 IDE.  Typically c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vb98\vb6.exe.  Set a breakpoint on the method you want to debug.

Press F5 and the VB6 ide will start running.  Load or create your vb6 project.  Note how you can add the path to the .vbp project in the previous step so it will automatically load your project.

Start debugging your vb6 project as usual.  As soon as it starts using your [ComVisible] C# class then your C# assembly gets loaded.  And the breakpoint will hit when your vb6 code calls the method.  Switch back and forth as needed.  Note that you cannot single-step from vb6 to C# code, you have to set breakpoints to get the debugger to stop.

Comment: Hi Hans, I have just tried your solution. It errors with "Automation Error The system cannot find the file specified"

NOTE: the .net dll contains a [COMVisible(true)] class and methods. There is a copy of the C# assembly and .tlb in the same directory as the vb6 project. And finally, the .Net assembly was compiled using VS2010.

is there a specific way of loading the C# assembly in VB6?

Comment: That's a completely different question, be sure to ask it.  In short, the CLR has no reason whatsoever to look in the vb6 project directory, it doesn't know anything about it.  It looks in the regasm.exe /codebase directory and the GAC for the [ComVisible] assembly and the vb98 directory and the GAC for dependent assemblies.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to see that.

Comment: Nice, I thought it was possible but hadn't tried it so I didn't know how they're interact, hence the "not easily" :)

Comment: @HansPassant Hmmm, now that you mentioned GAC, I might try that again...I have not registered the .Net DLL using gacutil, as I have read somewhere that you only need to register the .Net dll using regasm. I'm new to VB6 (coded mostly on C#) so pardon my lack of knowledge, also currently looking at how to use Fuslogvw.exe thanks

Comment: @HansPassant Also, I have updated my question to clarify my problem. Thanks

Comment: @HansPassant you sir, are a genius. **"*It looks in the regasm.exe /codebase directory and the GAC for the [ComVisible] assembly and the vb98 directory and the GAC for dependent assemblies*"** I registered the Dll in GAC and now I seem to be able to debug through the VB6 code and the .NET code :D...However, I will need to confirm that it really works, gonna need to test if values are being passed between them properly, then I will update this thread.

Thanks, I'm not sure if I could mark your comment as an answer though :S

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the wonders of using .NET from VB6 in a debuggable manner.

- in the VB6 project compile options (reached using the Options button on the Make Project dialog window), choose the Compile to *Native Code*, *No Optimization*, and *Create Symbolic Debug Info* options. Then compile your VB6 project. These options allow proper VB6 binary-to-source mapping.
- Go to the Configuration Properties...Debugging property page of your solution and change the *Start Action* to launch your VB6 executable.
- In VS Solution Explorer, go to File...Add Existing Item and navigate to the folder containing the VB6 source code you want to debug. Double-click on the VB6 source code file you want to debug, and a source window should open in VS that allows you to set breakpoints in the VB6 source code.
- Make sure that your .NET library has a public default constructor. This is essential.
- Now also set any C# breakpoints that you need. Do **not** step into the .NET code - this doesn't work.
- When you start debugging with VS, your VB6 and C# breakpoints should be hit normally.

Comment: I am not getting a source window opening where I follow your steps, hope you didn't mean I can open the VB6 code in VS2010.

Comment: @Knoxxios, yes you can open and debug VB6 source code in VS2010. I did it just now. What happened when you double-clicked on the VB6 source code file?

Comment: The source file opens just fine (as expected it shows errors as the project is in C#, however this does not affect the C# project (again as expected)). The problem is I can't debug through that VB6 source code :(

Comment: @Knoxxios, did you compile your VB6 executable as suggested in my first bullet point?

Comment: Yes I did; I compiled it using the settings you suggested

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to debug each individually:

- Debugging the VB6 code can be done in the IDE after compiling the C# DLL and adding it as a reference to the VB6 project.
- Debugging the DLL with the VB6 host is possible in Visual Studio by compiling the VB6 project and using it in the project properties as the executable to run.

In some cases this is simpler/quicker than setting up the environment to debug both simultaneously.

This approach will require having at least the framework of each working beforehand.

Comment: When you say:

"Debugging the VB6 code can be done in the IDE on it's own after compiling and referencing the C# DLL."

do you mean creating the executable?

Comment: @Knoxxios No, Compiling the DLL. To debug or test either, you need to other compiled. Hence the need for a basic framework first. I've updated my answer a bit to clarify.

Comment: Oh in that case I have already tried that. I have compiled the C# assembly and referenced it in the VB6 project. I can debug the C# dll using your suggestion, but not the VB6 project.