# Debugging VB6 project that calls a Fortran dll

Tags: debugging, dll, vb6, fortran, visual-studio-debugging

Can we debug a VB6 application that is calling Fortran dll?

I have searched a question like mine([Debugging VB6 project that calls a .Net(C#) dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361711/debugging-vb6-project-that-calls-a-netc-dll)). According to Hans Passant's answer,I tried to "Select the 'Start external program' option", but I cannot find this option(fig. 1).

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and Intel Parallel Studio XE 2011.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: You cannot debug VB6 with VS2010.  VS2010 only has VB.net.  You need VS6 or VS1998 to debug VB6.

Comment: Thanks! Consequently, it seems that I have to debug the DLL with the VB.net or C application in VS2010.

Comment: In that case, if you have the .pdbs for the dll, copy them to the same directory, then startup the program and from VS,Debug/Attach to the program.  You can then navigate to the relevant fortran code and set a breakpoint.  Then try invoking it from the VB6 GUI and see if you hit the breakpoint.

Comment: You [can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367332/stepping-through-vb6-com-object-wrapped-by-net-class) debug VB6 in visual studio 2010. Just build it with symbols (build a PDB file). And I don't read Chinese but I think the "command" option in your screenshot is how you choose an exe to run. So that's the equivalent of external program.

Comment: The screenshot does not look like a VB6 project. I don't really understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -2):

You need to upgrade your VB6 project to VB 2010 based on following MSDN document.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bszew91f(v=vs.100).aspx

And then please reference cup's suggestion, add Fortran.pdb file to the same path with Fortran.dll and debug it use VS2010.

Comment: Note that the "upgrade" from VB6 to VB.Net is not necessarily a trivial task. And in general this is not always even a recommended thing to do. There are lots of other answers/discussions on the merits of that approach.

Comment: Hi DavelnCaz! I am puzzled about the sentence "There are lots of other answers/discussions on the merits of that approach" . Does it mean : ①There are better ways to "upgrade" from VB6 to VB.Net ;or ②There are better ways to debug VB6 project that calls a Fortran dll ?        I feel sorry to confirm this from you because I am not so skilled when using Engish.

Comment: @hello, VS2010 doesn't support the VB 6 project directly, so we need to use certain updated tools and the old VS version to help us update it, since the VB 6 was old language, Microsoft doesn't support the old language, my suggestion is that if possible, update it to the VB would be a better choice even if it is not easy like this document: http://ntcoder.com/bab/2011/09/20/convert-a-vb6-project-to-vb-net-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: @TX You can't "upgrade" from VB6 to VB.net, they are very different platforms, so it is really a code conversion. And yes, I think you could find a better way of debugging your VB6 program.