# Tracing VB6 runtime error by debugging it

Tags: debugging, vb6, runtime-error, windbg, callstack

I started using WinDbg to debug VB6 runtime errors but can't really get it to work, all I need is to know the source of the error (the procedure where the error comes from).

I created a small app to test and made it to throw an overflow runtime error like this:

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim a As Byte
    a = 1000
End Sub
```

I compiled it with "Create Symbolic debug Info" option checked to create the PDB file.

Then I attached the application to WinDbg and clicked the button to throw the error, but when I check the call stack I don't find any trace of the `Command1_Click` procedure. All I get is the following :

```
0:001> ~* k

   0  Id: 56c.173c Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffde000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0012ea08 7e419418 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
0012ea40 7e4249c4 USER32!NtUserWaitMessage+0xc
0012ea68 7e43a956 USER32!InternalDialogBox+0xd0
0012ed28 7e43a2bc USER32!SoftModalMessageBox+0x938
0012ee78 7e43a10b USER32!MessageBoxWorker+0x2ba
0012eee4 729af829 USER32!MessageBoxIndirectA+0xb8
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0012ef24 729af6a5 MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x411e9
0012ef4c 729af9a0 MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x41065
0012ef7c 729a3d68 MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x41360
0012efe0 729a3db6 MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x35728
0012f000 72a0c411 MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x35776
0012f01c 72a0c6f3 MSVBVM60!_vbaOnGoCheck+0xba
0012f05c 7c9032a8 MSVBVM60!EbGetErrorInfo+0x115
0012f080 7c90327a ntdll!ExecuteHandler2+0x26
0012f130 7c90e46a ntdll!ExecuteHandler+0x24
0012f130 7c812aeb ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xe
0012f484 72a10dcf kernel32!RaiseException+0x53
0012f4a4 72a0e228 MSVBVM60!EbGetHandleOfExecutingProject+0x22b3
0012f4b8 72a0e28c MSVBVM60!rtcDoEvents+0x131
0012f4c8 72a219ee MSVBVM60!rtcDoEvents+0x195
0012f644 72992667 MSVBVM60!_vbaUI1I2+0x12
0012f668 729f4657 MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x24027
0012f698 7299ce49 MSVBVM60!DllCanUnloadNow+0x149a5
0012f6c0 7299f97d MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x2e809
0012f71c 7299e22c MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x3133d
0012f740 7299dc6d MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x2fbec
0012f7ac 729c223a MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x2f62d
0012f92c 7299ce49 MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x53bfa
0012f954 7299f97d MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x2e809
0012f9b0 7e418734 MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x3133d
0012f9dc 7e418816 USER32!InternalCallWinProc+0x28
0012fa44 7e42927b USER32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x150
0012fa80 7e4292e3 USER32!SendMessageWorker+0x4a5
0012faa0 7e44ff7d USER32!SendMessageW+0x7f
0012fab8 7e4465d2 USER32!xxxButtonNotifyParent+0x41
0012fad4 7e425e94 USER32!xxxBNReleaseCapture+0xf8
0012fb58 7e43b082 USER32!ButtonWndProcWorker+0x6df
0012fb78 7e418734 USER32!ButtonWndProcA+0x5d
0012fba4 7e418816 USER32!InternalCallWinProc+0x28
0012fc0c 7e42a013 USER32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x150
0012fc3c 7e42a998 USER32!CallWindowProcAorW+0x98
0012fc5c 7299d082 USER32!CallWindowProcA+0x1b
0012fcc8 729f492d MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x2ea42
0012fcf0 7299ce49 MSVBVM60!DllCanUnloadNow+0x14c7b
0012fd18 7299f97d MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x2e809
0012fd74 7e418734 MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x3133d
0012fda0 7e418816 USER32!InternalCallWinProc+0x28
0012fe08 7e4189cd USER32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x150
0012fe68 7e4196c7 USER32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x306
0012fe78 7294a6c8 USER32!DispatchMessageA+0xf
0012feb8 7294a63f MSVBVM60!_vbaStrToAnsi+0x2f1
0012fefc 7294a51d MSVBVM60!_vbaStrToAnsi+0x268
0012ff18 7294a4e8 MSVBVM60!_vbaStrToAnsi+0x146
0012ff3c 72943644 MSVBVM60!_vbaStrToAnsi+0x111
0012ffb8 00401246 MSVBVM60!ThunRTMain+0xa0
0012fff0 00000000 Project1!__vbaS+0xa

#  1  Id: 56c.10a8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffdd000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  
00f0ffc8 7c950010 ntdll!DbgBreakPoint
00f0fff4 00000000 ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin+0x2d
```

Note that WinDbg doesn't break on the error, so I manually break into it after I get the error message and before clicking OK, because if I clicked OK, the application closes.

I'm new to WinDbg but I read that it should break on error but it doesn't, all I get is "First chance Exception" and I don't get a "Second chance Exception" when I click OK and let it crash.

I think that somehow WinDbg considers that VB6 handled the error even though it didn't handle it. Is there something I'm missing here? How can I get the trace of the error to the calling procedure?

Comment: Here's a [2006 blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marklon/archive/2006/01/28/518616.aspx) by a Microsoft guy about using Windbg with VB6. Can I ask why you have to use WinDbg? Other options are VB6's own debugger or [later versions of Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367332/stepping-through-vb6-com-object-wrapped-by-net-class)

Comment: I already read that and others but it doesn't help about my problem, i don't have to use WinDbg, I even tried msvc++ debugger but same problem, what I need is to be able to detect the source of the error (the procedure) when a client calls and complains about unhandled error in my app and I can't get enough informations from him to know where the error could be.. So i plan to make the app take a dump image when there's an error and analyze it with the debugger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running the application in VB6 itself results in a VB6 runtime error 6, which stands for "overflow".

### First chance exception

Running the application under WinDbg (6.2.9200), I first see a

```
(6cc.6d4): Unknown exception - code c000008f (first chance)
```

which is probably the most common VB6 exception. By default, WinDbg does not break on first chance exceptions of this type. If you want it to do so, you need to enable that explicitly by

```
sxe c000008f
```

### Second chance exception

The first chance exception is followed by a message box

[image: VB6 runtime error message box]

This message box is the first indicator that the exception must have been caught, otherwise there would have been a second chance exception immediately afterwards.

And in fact, VB6 creates an exception handler:

```
0:000> u
Project1!Form1::Command_Click [Form1 @ 5]:
004019a0 55              push    ebp
004019a1 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
004019a3 83ec0c          sub     esp,0Ch
004019a6 68b6104000      push    offset Project1!__vbaExceptHandler (004010b6)
004019ab 64a100000000    mov     eax,dword ptr fs:[00000000h]
...
004019df b9e8030000      mov     ecx,3E8h
004019e4 ff1530104000    call    dword ptr [Project1!_imp___vbaUI1I2 (00401030)]
...
```

At `004019a6` you see that VB6 is working with `__vbaExceptHandler`. `mov dword ptr fs:[0],esp` is the beginning of a try/catch block. At `004019df` it stores 0x3E8 (hex) or 1000 (dec) to ECX. That's where your code is.

After confirming the message, the process terminates, but not due to a second chance exception but because of an `ExitProcess()` call. That's the way VB6 "handles" exceptions.

```
0:000> k
ChildEBP RetAddr  
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0012ff28 7c81bfb6 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
0012ff3c 73393657 kernel32!ExitProcess+0x14
0012ffb8 0040113a MSVBVM60!ThunRTMain+0xb3
0012fff0 00000000 image00400000+0x113a
```

### Symbols

To see if the symbols have been loaded correctly, type `lm` (list modules). It should look like this:

```
0:000> lm
start    end        module name
00400000 00404000   Project1   (private pdb symbols)  C:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\Project1.pdb
```

If you see `(deferred)`, the symbols have not been loaded yet. Type `ld Project1` to load them.

With symbols, you can set breakpoints by first finding the method with `x` and then setting a breakpoint `bp`:

```
0:000> x Project1!Form1*
004019a0          Project1!Form1::Command_Click (void)

0:000> bp Project1!Form1::Command_Click

0:000> bl
 0 e 004019a0     0001 (0001)  0:**** Project1!Form1::Command_Click

[...]

Breakpoint 0 hit
eax=004016b4 ebx=00000001 ecx=00000000 edx=733a3dd8 esi=0012f5e4 edi=0012f514
eip=004019a0 esp=0012f50c ebp=0012f514 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000216
Project1!Form1::Command_Click:
004019a0 55              push    ebp

0:000> k
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0012f508 733e1ce3 Project1!Form1::Command_Click [Form1 @ 5]
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0012f524 733e1fe4 MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x23703
...
```

But a breakpoint is not what you wanted...

### Why the method is not on the call stack

Unfortunately enabling first chance exceptions and loading symbols does still not help seeing the method on the call stack at the time the exception is thrown. It's somewhere in `DoEvents()`:

```
0:000> .exr -1
ExceptionAddress: 7c812fd3 (kernel32!RaiseException+0x00000052)
   ExceptionCode: c000008f
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: deadcafe
   Parameter[1]: deadcafe

0:000> k
ChildEBP RetAddr  
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0012f484 73460c29 kernel32!RaiseException+0x52
0012f4a4 7345e082 MSVBVM60!EbGetHandleOfExecutingProject+0x22b3
0012f4b8 7345e0e6 MSVBVM60!rtcDoEvents+0x131
...
```

Have you noticed the warning about the stack unwind information? Let's look at the stack manually:

```
0:000> dps @ebp
0012f484  0012f4a4
0012f488  73460c29 MSVBVM60!EbGetHandleOfExecutingProject+0x22b3
0012f48c  c000008f
0012f490  00000001
0012f494  00000002
0012f498  0012f49c
0012f49c  deadcafe
0012f4a0  deadcafe
...
0012f4d8  004019e7 Project1!Form1::Command_Click+0x53 [Form1 @ 7]
0012f4dc  0012f514
0012f4e0  0012f5e4
0012f4e4  00000001
0012f4e8  00000000
0012f4ec  00000000
0012f4f0  00000000
0012f4f4  0012fa34
0012f4f8  004010b6 Project1!__vbaExceptHandler
```

I guess you can't do anything about it. VB6 is not very good in creating symbols and also not in maintaining a nice call stack.

Comment: Whether this is a blessing or a curse is in the eye of the beholder.  As a developer I appreciate everything VB6 does (by intention or by quirk) that helps defeat cracking and other reverse-engineering efforts.  If you seek a soft target look to .Net code.

Comment: @Bob77: interesting point of view. Did you try C++ on x64? That's a totally new calling convention. Things are passed in registers and can be optimized by the compiler. Quite hard to get things right.

Comment: Well explained..but can you tell me what does the command `dps @ebp` exactly do? And how can it work with dumped image.. Or if its not.. Is there a way to get the last method called of my application (not api) out of the dumped image?

Comment: @MohamedGharib: `dps` is the command for "**d**ump **p**ointer-sized data and resolve **s**ymbols". `@ebp` refers to a register which points to the stack ("**e**xtended **b**ase **p**ointer")

Comment: @ThomasWaller: Thanks for the explanation.. I tried it on a dumped image and didn't work so i gave up the idea of WinDbg although i really wanted it to work and now i'm working on some kind of CallStack for vb6 to help me debugging the unhandled errors.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, but I can totally understand. If you have the option to get a call stack another way or do logging etc. it may really be the easier option. You might want MZ-Tools (an old version is free) which can generate exception handlers for you.